# How to remove extra slash in url

Tags: html, url, iis, iis-7

Hello I am having following URL while i am running my application from IIS

```
http://localhost/ABC/app/login/login.html/?#
```

I am not getting from where it is adding extra slash after **login.html**
I want to remove that and make URL as follow:

```
http://localhost/ABC/app/login/login.html?#
```

if i enter above desire url in browser still it add **/** (slash) character after **login.html**

Is there some setting to remove this **/** (slash)character.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25817317/1248133

Comment: Not working for me. or can you give me exact expression to modify url